# Limit Relief plot output to specified X and y range

Tags: plotting, bugs

I have a table of values and I'd like to use `ReliefPlot` to visualise. Is it possible through the plot command to limit the $x,y$ range displayed?

The help suggests `PlotRange->{{1, 5}, {1, 10}}` should do this, but this appears to limit the $z$ output not $x,y$.

I know I can pull out bits of the table, create a new one, then plot that, but this is rather inefficient when exploring the output.

Comment: Try `PlotRange->{{1,5},{1,10}, Full}`

Comment: I agree that something looks strange in the [ReliefPlot documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReliefPlot.html). The example that says "Use an explicit _x_ range and  _y_ range to focus on areas of interest" with `PlotRange -> {{100, 200}, {200, 300}}`looks identical to the preceeding one with `PlotRange->Automatic`....Could this be a bug?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Edmund, however for me that isn't limiting the x/y range.

Comment: @Rashid I suspect it is a bug if I'm not misunderstanding what's said there.

Comment: Esme, @Edmund I agree with you both that something fishy is going on here. Esme may have been missing a `DataRange` directive, nonetheless the documentation explicitly mentions that `PlotRange` should interact with the `DataRange`, but it doesn't in MMA 10.4.0 (Win7-64). It is funny to see that the online docs also show an incorrect output for that particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you stumbled upon a **bug** in `ReliefPlot`.

```
data = Table[Sin[x] Cos[2 y] + 0.1 x, {x, -10, 10, 0.05}, {y, -10, 10, 0.05}];

ReliefPlot[data,
 DataRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-8, 5}, All},
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

According to the documentation for v. 10.4, `PlotRange` should "interact with `DataRange`", which I take to mean that one can specify a plot range using the transformed coordinated generated by the data range, rather than the row/column numbers when an explicit `DataRange` directive is provided.

In fact, however, this doesn't happen, as shown above. The documentation also contains seemingly contradictory results:

[image: from docs]

Although from the description one would expect the plot range of the resulting plot to be restricted, it actually isn't.